# Losing responsiveness when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, backgroundworker

To simplify I'll strip the business rules behind:

I'm fetching data from WCF and filling out the grid. In background I'm checking if record already exists, if not - I'm adding it to table via EF. Everything is fine and responsive until it comes to actions with EF. Code looks like this:

```
var ds = client.GetInfo(id,cb_TrackMembers_StartDate.Checked ? dtp_StartDate.Value
                                                                 : (DateTime?)null,
                                                             cb_EndDate.Checked
                                                                 ? dtp_EndDate.Value
                                                                 : (DateTime?)null,
                                                             cb_CompletedOnly.Checked);
        DataTable tables = ds.Tables["Table1"];
        async_fillgridwithdatatable(gv_source, tables);


private void async_fillgridwithdatatable(DataGridView grid, DataTable table)
    {
        MethodInvoker action = delegate
            {
                grid.Rows.Clear();
                var existing = db.GetMemberList();
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    var username = row["Q51_1"].ToString();
                    if (!existing.Contains(username))
                    {
                        MyDirHelper ldap = new MyDirHelper(username, "");
                        int acclvl = ldap.GetAccessLevel();
                        tbl_Member newMember = new tbl_Member
                            {
                                username = username,
                                first_name = row["Q9_1"].ToString(),
                                last_name = row["Q9_2"].ToString(),
                                .
                                .
                                .
                                id_accesslevel = db.DB_GetMemberAutoAccessLevelIDByLDAPAccessLevel(acclvl),
                                created_on = DateTime.Now,
                                created_by = db.GetUser(E_Username).id_user,
                                modified_by = db.GetUser(E_Username).id_user,
                                modified_on = DateTime.Now
                            };
                        db.InsertIntoMembersEntity(newMember);
                        if (newMember.id_accesslevel != 1)
                        {
                            if (newMember.id_accesslevel != null)
                            {
                                mail_sendWelcome(newMember.email, newMember.id_accesslevel.Value);
                                db.UpdateMemberWelcomeMailSentDate(newMember.id_member, DateTime.Now);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tbl_Member existingMember = db.GetMemberByLogin(username);

                                existingMember.first_name = row["Q9_1"].ToString();
                                existingMember.last_name = row["Q9_2"].ToString();
                                .
                                .
                                .
                                existingMember.modified_by = db.GetUser(E_Username).id_user;
                                existingMember.modified_on = DateTime.Now;

                        db.Save();
                    }
                    grid.Rows.Add(username);
                }
            };
        grid.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
```

Is there any way to improve responsiveness here?

Comment: To "loose" responsiveness would mean to set it free... remove restriction on it. The image is that performance is now the best it can be. So "loose" instead of "lose" means the opposite of what you intended.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Right, thanks! I could remind myself about "set sth loose"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the code is executed in the UI thread in your case, because the [Control.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) method is not supposed to run a delegate in a background thread. To execute the code asynchronously, use the BeginInvoke method of a delegate. For example:

```
private void async_fillgridwithdatatable(DataGridView grid, DataTable table)
{
    Func<DataTable, IEnumerable<string>> action = new Func<DataTable, IEnumerable<string>>(UpdateDbAndGetData);
    action.BeginInvoke(o => grid.Invoke(new Action<IEnumerable<string>>(rows => {
                                grid.Rows.Clear();
                                foreach (string username in rows)
                                    grid.Rows.Add(username);    
                            }), 
        action.EndInvoke(o)));
}

IEnumerable<String> UpdateDbAndGetData(DataTable table) {
    var existing = db.GetMemberList();
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        var username = row["Q51_1"].ToString();
        if (!existing.Contains(username))
        {
            MyDirHelper ldap = new MyDirHelper(username, "");
            int acclvl = ldap.GetAccessLevel();
            tbl_Member newMember = new tbl_Member
                {
                    username = username,
                    first_name = row["Q9_1"].ToString(),
                    last_name = row["Q9_2"].ToString(),
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    id_accesslevel = db.DB_GetMemberAutoAccessLevelIDByLDAPAccessLevel(acclvl),
                    created_on = DateTime.Now,
                    created_by = db.GetUser(E_Username).id_user,
                    modified_by = db.GetUser(E_Username).id_user,
                    modified_on = DateTime.Now
                };
            db.InsertIntoMembersEntity(newMember);
            if (newMember.id_accesslevel != 1)
            {
                if (newMember.id_accesslevel != null)
                {
                    mail_sendWelcome(newMember.email, newMember.id_accesslevel.Value);
                    db.UpdateMemberWelcomeMailSentDate(newMember.id_member, DateTime.Now);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tbl_Member existingMember = db.GetMemberByLogin(username);

                    existingMember.first_name = row["Q9_1"].ToString();
                    existingMember.last_name = row["Q9_2"].ToString();
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    existingMember.modified_by = db.GetUser(E_Username).id_user;
                    existingMember.modified_on = DateTime.Now;

            db.Save();
        }
        yield return username;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still unable to fix the issue. While changing my code to your conception I ended up with 2 error saying: 

1) `new Func<IEnumerable<string>>(UpdateDbAndGetData);` -> No overload for 'UpdateDbAndGetData' matches delegate 'System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>' so probably this needs to be changed so `UpdateDbAndGetData` would accept DataTable as parameter as in IEnumerableString method signature

2) `action.BeginInvoke(...` -> No overload for method 'BeginInvoke' takes 1 arguments

Still cannot get it working to update the grid just after adding to database.

Comment: Hi, Adrian! Indeed, there was an error in my code. The delegate should have a parameter of the DataTable type. I have corrected this error in my answer. As for the second parameter of the BeginInvoke method, I used the action.EndInvoke() result in my code snippet. Possibly, you have missed this part.